# How to use combination of over- and undersampling? with imbalanced learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, oversampling, imblearn, imbalanced-data

I want to resample some big data (class sizes: 8mio vs 2700)
I would like to have 50.000 samples of each by oversampling class 2 und undersampling class 1.
imblearn seems to offer a cominbation of over- and undersampling but i dont get how it works.

```
from collections import Counter
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC
from imblearn.under_sampling import TomekLinks
from imblearn.combine import SMOTETomek

smt = SMOTETomek(random_state=1)
X_resamp, y_resamp = smt.fit_resample(data_all[29000:30000], labels_all[29000:30000])
```

Before the data looked like

```
>>Counter(labels_all[29000:30000])
>>Counter({0: 968, 9: 32})
```

and afterwards

```
>>Counter(y_resamp)
>>Counter({0: 968, 9: 968})
```

as I would expect or wish for something like

```
>>Counter(y_resamp)
>>Counter({0: 100, 9: 100})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only have 32 records with class `9`, so it over sample that class and align it's data records with those of class `0` hence  `9: 968`

you are talking about reduce the data set to 100 record, you can do it be sampling 100 records randomly for each class, from `X` and `Y` (same 100 records) or take the first 100 like `y_resamp[:100]`

Comment: yeah you're right i was just expecting a combination of over and undersampling like `SMOTETomek` could do that in one step. 
Now i first downsample class 0 by `data_all[labels_all==0].sample(100)` and afterards oversample the reduced data set using 'SMOTE'. I was just hoping there was a more sophisticated solution as randomly downsampling. 
I am downsampling 8.5m obversations to 10.000 so I wish there was way to get the 10.000 most diverse observations.